# Angular body isnt passing correctly on post request

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple post api which is working fine in postman when i try to send it by angular its not passing.

I am doing like this

```
  var body : any= {"Name": this.registerForm.value.name, "ArabicName": this.registerForm.value.arname, "Description": this.registerForm.value.description,  "Image": "sample string 5",
  "DisplayOrder": 1,
  "StatusID": 1,
  "UpdatedBy": 1};

  const headers2 = new HttpHeaders()
.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log(body);
  this.http.post("http://itserviceapi.airtechsolutions.pk/api/admin/category/insert", {body, headers2}).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

When i console my body it look like this

[image]

And in postman body look like this

[image]

I need to know where is the issue i think i need to convert in json or something ?

Comment: is simply `this.http.post("http://itserviceapi.airtechsolutions.pk/api/admin/category/insert", body)` -Angular by defect send in json- if you want add a headers, is the third param: `this.http.post("http://itserviceapi.airtechsolutions.pk/api/admin/category/insert", body, headers2)`

Answer (score 0):

You're sending body and header as a single parameter in a object which might be causing problem. Body should be send as a second parameter and headers should be your third parameter. Something like below;

```
this.http.post("http://itserviceapi.airtechsolutions.pk/api/admin/category/insert", body, { headers: headers2 })
```